# What am I missing in this access SQL query?

Tags: sql, ms-access

I am trying to pull specific information from several tables using the INNER JOIN function and I think I have a problem with my syntax - thinking too many or too few (). What does the community think?

```
SELECT Employee.EmployeeID
    ,Service.HoursWorked
FROM (
    Equipment INNER JOIN (Equipment Repair)
        ON Equipment.EquipmentID = Equipment Repair.RepairID
    )
INNER JOIN (
    (
        (
            Service INNER JOIN EMPLOYEE
                ON Service.ProductID = EMPLOYEE.EmployeeID
            ) INNER JOIN (
            OWNER INNER JOIN Property
                ON OWNER.OwnerID = Property.OwnerID
            )
        INNER JOIN SubProperty
            ON Property.PropertyID = SubProperty.PropertyID
        )
    ON Service.PropertyID = Subproperty.PropertyID
    )
INNER JOIN TrainingCourse
    ON EMPLOYEE.EmployeeID = TrainingCourse.EmployeeID
        ON Equipment.EquipmentID = TrainingCourse.EquipmentID ORDER BY Employee.EmployeeID
```

Comment: Please proper format your code first before asking. Maybe after that you could see your problem without needing any help.

Comment: Which flavour of SQL you are using, like MySQL, SQL Server, etc., tag the appropriate tech

Comment: `INNER JOIN` is not a function, and your SQL is a total mess (not including the formatting). Start by counting the number of `(` characters, then count the number of `)` characters. If they're not equal, you've identified part of the problem.

Comment: @Sankar: The title says Access, and there's an Access tag. My guess would be that the tech is MS Access. :-)

Comment: @KenWhite when I entered the comment, it was only taged with `sql`. But I didn't noticed the title though :D

Comment: Are you using Access query designer? That should get correct syntax.

Answer (score -1):

Your query is attempting to join several tables together, but you are perhaps trying to use parentheses as well? Those don't have the effect you might be expecting here.

Without the (apparently?) spurious parentheses, I would understand that query as meaning this:

```sql
SELECT
    Employee.EmployeeID
    ,Service.HoursWorked
FROM Equipment
    INNER JOIN (Equipment Repair)
        ON Equipment.EquipmentID = Equipment Repair.RepairID
    INNER JOIN Service
    INNER JOIN EMPLOYEE
        ON Service.ProductID = EMPLOYEE.EmployeeID
    INNER JOIN OWNER
    INNER JOIN Property
        ON OWNER.OwnerID = Property.OwnerID
    INNER JOIN SubProperty
        ON Property.PropertyID = SubProperty.PropertyID
        ON Service.PropertyID = Subproperty.PropertyID
    INNER JOIN TrainingCourse
        ON EMPLOYEE.EmployeeID = TrainingCourse.EmployeeID
        ON Equipment.EquipmentID = TrainingCourse.EquipmentID
ORDER BY Employee.EmployeeID
```

But that still has errors, because many of the joins are lacking join conditions and some have multiple join conditions.

Instead, you need to think of the [projection operation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Projection_(relational_algebra)) that you are trying to express. What columns, from what tables, should appear in the result set (this tells you which tables to join), and under what condition should a row from table Foo appear in the total result set (this tells you the join condition for that table).

Comment: Access sql bothers a lot with parenthesis